# Does PSYoungGen has initial space, why no instance created,but some space is used?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

```
/* jvm:" -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Xms20M -Xmx20M -Xmn10M -XX:SurvivorRatio=8 "*/
 public class testGC {
        private final static int _1MB = 1024*1024;

        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            testAllocation();
              }

        public static void testAllocation()
        {
            byte[] allocation1,allocation2,allocation3,allocation4;

           System.gc();

        }

    }
```

running result: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe"
-XX:+PrintGCDetails -Xms20M -Xmx20M -Xmn10M -XX:SurvivorRatio=8 "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition
2018.1.6\lib\idea_rt.jar=60552:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.1.6\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\rt.jar;F:\JAVA\testGC\target\classes" com.zhangbing.testGC.testGC [GC (System.gc()) [PSYoungGen: 2020K->744K(9216K)] **2020K->752K(no instance created why there is 2020k is used and can be collected to 752)**(19456K), 0.0008220 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs]  [Full GC (System.gc()) [PSYoungGen: 744K->0K(By the way what is ok means and why it is 744 but not 752)(9216K)] [ParOldGen: 8K->617K(10240K)] 752K->617K(19456K), [Metaspace: 3335K->3335K(1056768K)], 0.0033393 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs]  Heap  PSYoungGen    total 9216K, used 246K [0x00000000ff600000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)   eden space 8192K, 3% used [0x00000000ff600000,0x00000000ff63d890,0x00000000ffe00000)   from space 1024K, 0% used [0x00000000ffe00000,0x00000000ffe00000,0x00000000fff00000)   to   space 1024K, 0% used [0x00000000fff00000,0x00000000fff00000,0x0000000100000000)  ParOldGen  total 10240K, used 617K [0x00000000fec00000, 0x00000000ff600000, 0x00000000ff600000)   object space 10240K, 6% used [0x00000000fec00000,0x00000000fec9a7a0,0x00000000ff600000)  Metaspace  used 3356K, capacity 4496K, committed 4864K, reserved 1056768K   class space    used 368K, capacity 388K, committed 512K, reserved 1048576K

Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although *your* code does not create any objects, plenty of objects will be created during the initialization of the JVM alone.

For example your class uses the `System.class` which means that before your code can run to completion the `System` class must be loaded and initialized. All the static initializer code must be run which can easily create objects.

Also, your class derives off `Object`, so that must be initialized. The same is true for `String` (which is used as an argument type to your `main` method).

All of these classes need to be loaded from the file system (requiring a good chunk of `java.io` to be initialized).

**tl;dr** tons of classes are loaded and objects are created *long* before your `main` method is even reached.

Comment: thank you,By the way for "PSYoungGen: 744K->0K" what does "ok" means and why it is 744 but not 752.

Comment: It is not "ok".  It is "0k" .  Zero kilobytes.  For the rest, if you formatted your Question properly, it would be easier to see what you are asking.  Please do that.